# One entity, two repositories in symfony

Tags: symfony

I would like use 2 repository for 1 entity.

The reason is : I have 2 bundles, both bundle use the same entity. I wish to separate both functionalities. 
Sometimes I need specific queries into bundle.

It is possible to have 1 repository into a bundle and a second repository in the other one ? 
Maybe it's a wrong way ?

If someone have an idea.

Thx !

Comment: If you use the same entity why don't you want to use the same class Repository?

Comment: Because it's two different functionalities

For exemple, if I make a site for a car renting, I have a bundle for renting, and sometime I need to repair some cars  

I have a bundle renting, and an other one repair, and I want to separate the renting's queries and the repair's queries

Comment: So, create two methods in your repo.

Comment: I had edit my previous message with an exemple.
For you, it's a good idea to add all queries on the same repository ?

Comment: All the query who depend of the same entity, yes

Comment: You can make it so the function names start depending on the functionality. That way, you and people following you, will have a "separate" way of understanding what does what. But, in the end, one repository is better than two.

Comment: Within a given entity manager you can only have one repository per entity.  You could have two entity managers with independent repositories, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html, but I am not sure that is what you are looking for.  I would suggest making two services (CarRentingService and CarRepairService) and inject the CarRepository into them as Thomas has answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 2019 Update

I'd create 2 repositories. It makes no sense to add all methods to one repository, just because they share the entity. We could end up with 30 methods per repository this way.

### First repository

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

final class FrontendPostRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Post::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return Post[]
     */
    public function getAll(): array
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

### ...and 2nd repository

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

final class AdminPostRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Post::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return Post[]
     */
    public function getUnpublished(): array
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

### You can read more about this concept and *whys* in [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/) post

Comment: My first idea was to separate both activites because I think like you, it's two different things.
I had tried to create two repositories but in symfony, when you use the ORM annotation @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=""), I think you only can have one repository.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you advise to make queries in manager, not in repo ?

Comment: I don't use `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="")` approach. 
Sort off. Personally, I'd take a trial with these 2 classes, then it would be obvious what to do next. You already stopped before creating one big repository, so it's probably the way to go for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't really know it's a good practice but you can create a repository without linked entity (I mean, not with ORM annotation)

So I just create this in my service.yml :

```
renting.metadata.car:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata
    arguments: [ %car% ]
```

And this :

```
repair.repository.car:
    class: carRepository
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @renting.metadata.car]
```

That's works